How to update sharepoint datasource credentials of PowerBI dataset programmatically?
I have an azure devops cicd pipeline for powerbi automation in which i want to update credential for sharepoint in parameters i have 2 params one sql credential and one for sharepoint i have below script for sql credentials it is working well
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Write-Host

$applicationId = "$(appid)"
$securePassword = "$(clientsecret-value)" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $securePassword
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId "$(TenantID)"

# update these parameters for target workspace and dataset 

$datasetName = $(datasetConfigdev)

$datasetnames = $datasetName

foreach($datasetname in $datasetnames){
    echo "---"
    echo "datasetname : $datasetname"
    
$workspaceName = $(workspacenamedev)
$dataset_Name = $datasetname
# add credentials for SQL datasource
$sqlUserName = 'readonly'
$sqlUserPassword = 'mpf2$d#v'


# get object for target workspace
$workspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Name $workspaceName

# get object for new dataset
$dataset = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $workspace.Id | Where-Object Name -eq $dataset_Name

# get object for new SQL datasource
$datasource = Get-PowerBIDatasource -WorkspaceId $workspace.Id -DatasetId $dataset.Id

# parse REST to determine gateway Id and datasource Id
$workspaceId = $workspace.Id
$datasetId = $dataset.Id
$datasourceUrl = "groups/$workspaceId/datasets/$datasetId/datasources"

# execute REST call to determine gateway Id and datasource Id
$datasourcesResult = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Get -Url $datasourceUrl | ConvertFrom-Json

# parse REST URL used to patch datasource credentials
$datasource = $datasourcesResult.value[0]
$gatewayId = $datasource.gatewayId
$datasourceId = $datasource.datasourceId
$datasourePatchUrl = "gateways/$gatewayId/datasources/$datasourceId"

# create HTTP request body to patch datasource credentials
$patchBody = @{
  "credentialDetails" = @{
    "credentials" = "{""credentialData"":[{""name"":""username"",""value"":""$sqlUserName""},{""name"":""password"",""value"":""$sqlUserPassword""}]}"
    "credentialType" = "Basic"
    "encryptedConnection" =  "Encrypted"
    "encryptionAlgorithm" = "None"
    "privacyLevel" = "Organizational"
  }
}

# convert body contents to JSON
$patchBodyJson = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $patchBody -Depth 6 -Compress

# execute PATCH request to set datasource credentials
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Patch -Url $datasourePatchUrl -Body $patchBodyJson

# parse REST URL for dataset refresh
#$datasetRefreshUrl = "groups/$workspaceId/datasets/$datasetId/refreshes"

# execute POST to begin dataset refresh
#Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Post -Url $datasetRefreshUrl -WarningAction Ignore

}

Now i  have two params sql and sharepoint i want to authenticate sharepoint data source with OAuth 2.0 credentials how can i pass both credential in one script
Want to pass both sql and sharepoint credential
